# How to insert values to MySql database? PHP v5.5, libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev

Tags: php, mysql

I had 2 months break in programming. Now php scripts does not work. What have changed in the syntax? I had php v5.3 two months ago. Now it is installed php 5.5 ; database client version is libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev;

The code which was working two months before, but does not work now:

```
$str1="INSERT INTO ".$vtbname." (tcdbname, tctname, tccolname, tcbComp) VALUES ( '$vdbname', '$vtbnameFrom', '$colname', 0)";
$ans1 =  mysqli_query( $conn, $str1 );
if(! $ans1  ) { die('<br>1. Could not enter data to: '.$vdbname.'.'.$vtbname.' : '. mysqli_error()); }
else { echo "<br>1.Inserted successfully to ".$vdbname.".".$vtbname;}
echo "<br>str1=".$str1;
```

The syntax shown in PhpMyAdmin, but it does not work from script:

```
$str1="INSERT INTO `".$vdbname."`.`".$vtbname."` (`tcdbname`, `tctname`, `tccolname`, `tcbComp`,) VALUES ( '".$vdbname."', '".$vtbnameFrom."', '".$colname."', '0')";
$ans1 =  mysqli_query( $conn, $str1 );
if(! $ans1  ) { die('<br>1. Could not enter data to: '.$vdbname.'.'.$vtbname.' : '. mysqli_error()); }
else { echo "<br>1.Inserted successfully to ".$vdbname.".".$vtbname;}
echo "<br>str1=".$str1;
```

In both cases values are not inserted i am getting error and str1 is echoed for debuging purposes:

```
str1=INSERT INTO `gintare_calendar`.`tinfotlogin` (`tcdbname`, `tctname`, `tccolname`, `tcbComp`) VALUES ( 'gintare_calendar', 'tlogin', 'tcid' '0')
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\CreateInfoDBsimple.php on line 90
```

Comment: Give the connection parameter as an argument to your `mysqli_error($conn);` as shown.

Comment: what error messages you got please mention that errors

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `,` in this line

```
$str1="INSERT INTO `".$vdbname."`.`".$vtbname."` (`tcdbname`, `tctname`, `tccolname`, `tcbComp`,) VALUES ( '".$vdbname."', '".$vtbnameFrom."', '".$colname."', '0')";
```

Change this to :

```
$str1="INSERT INTO `".$vdbname."`.`".$vtbname."` (`tcdbname`, `tctname`, `tccolname`,`tcbComp`) VALUES ( '".$vdbname."', '".$vtbnameFrom."', '".$colname."', '0')";
```

Comment: Thanks. I made this error with comma when shortened query statement. The commas are correct. The error was is wrong column number. Thanks for reminding about $conn parameter in mysql error. It resolved questions saying that number of columns does not match number of values.